# Spring external resource

Tags: java, spring, file, load, external

I wanted Spring to load external file where executable .jar is and i have some question:

1. Is loading file with Bean Resource, then use application context to get external file is ok?
2. Is `applicationContext.getResource("/test.json")` will try to load test.json where executable .jar is? If yes, then this path "/test.json" is ok?
3. Is "getResource" loads resource before application runs?
   If im wrong, can you please give me example how to do what i wanted to do ;) ?
   Regards!

Comment: What do you want to do with this file? Generally loading should be done through springs resource loading abstraction (use the narrowest interface possible) not the `ApplicationContext`. But it also depends on what you want to do with the properties file. What is also good to know is if you are using Spring Boot or not?

Comment: This json file will have configuration with mapping that user can edit before application starts, im using Spring Boot

Comment: Just load the file using the `ResourceLoader` (the `ApplicationContext` is a `ResourceLoader` but use the narrowest interface possible). use `getResource` if it is external prefix with `file:` else it will use the class path. I suggest a read of the resource loading chapter in the Spring Reference Guide.